# Difference: Ihr vs sie

Tags: difference, personal-pronoun, salutation

**Plurals of personal pronouns**

The personal pronoun *sie* can be regarded as *they*, but also *Ihr* can. What's the difference between the plural *sie* and *Ihr*? (I'm assuming that *Ihr* is not just a polite way of saying *sie*.)

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly: in _'sie' can be regarded as 'they', but also 'Ihr'_ do you mean _Ihr = sie_ or _Ihr = they_? Could there be a typo somewhere? Or could you maybe please add a source to that issue?

Comment: I wouldn't say *sie* can be regarded as *Ihr*. We don't use *Ihr* as polite form regularly. It is mostly an old way or preserved locally, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6flichkeitsform#Anrede_in_der_2._Person_Plural_(Ihr) . So *sie* is *they*, but *Sie* (capital 'S') is *you* in the polite form in singular and plural.  *Ihr* and *Sie* are therefore only related in the fact that they are both polite forms. *ihr* is 2nd person plural, but not a polite form.

Answer (score 13):

It is as follows:

- *du* → *you* (singular)

> Hast *du* das getan? → Did *you* do that?

- *ihr* → *you* (plural)

> Habt *ihr* das getan? → Did *you* do that?

- *Ihr* → *you* (singular, [Pluralis Majestatis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralis_Majestatis), not to be confused with the [Royal we](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we))

> Habt *Ihr* das getan, mein König? → Did *you* do that, my King?

- *Sie* → *you* (singular or plural, [honorific](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6flichkeitsform))

> Haben *Sie* das getan? → Did *you* do that?

- *sie* → *they* (plural) or *she* (singular)

> Haben *sie* das getan? → Did *they* do that?
>
> Hat *sie* das getan? → Did *she* do that?

In summary:

- *du*, *ihr*, *Ihr*, *Sie*   ⇄   *you*
- *sie*   ⇆   *they*, *she*

Comment: Hi, I'm Chinese. Though you answered the question, I don't understand why when `Sie` is changed only one character `s`, it becomes from `you` to `they`/`she`... There must be reason. I mean, in English that is `you`/`she`/`they`, in Spanish that is `tu`/`usted`/`ella`/`ellas`, in Chinese, we have `你`/`她`/`她们`. `You` and `They` are quite different~

Comment: @yarco it is because in Latin scripts, capital letters have a BIG meaning :) they are a way to be polite when talking to someone (just like you have 您). They are also a way to show respect for proper nouns like cities (London, etc.). In German they use capitals a lot more than in English, and it's simply important to remember when a capital makes a difference.